# Manwha in which the female lead dies and comes back after being stabbed

Tags: story-identification, magic, manga

I'm searching for a manhwa in which the female lead (FL) dies and comes back after being stabbed. She has red eyes and her hair looks kinda purple/blue. She has a blonde/ginger sister that is obsessed with family reputation; I think the sister's name is Viat. If I remember correctly, the FL absorbs some sort of red magical stone power and pretends to be clueless to the family, while gathering information. I forgot the name, so if any of you could help I would be very grateful. :)

Comment: Yes! This is it! Thank you, i mistook the eye/hair colors but you still helped me, thank you so much :)

Comment: If the answer below is correct, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is ***[I'm the Master of this Life](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/l80evhy/i-m-the-master-of-this-life)***.

From [Anime-Planet](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/im-the-master-of-this-life):

> The guardian stone of the family appeared to me. To me, the illegitimate child, not my half-sister who is the enemy. Since then, the treatment of me has changed. It really felt like that I'm part of their family. However, as I died, I realized that it was all an illusion at the hands of my fiancée. That everything he did for me was a scheme by my half-sister to take the guardian stone. [Don't you want to take revenge on those who thoroughly deceived and killed you?] I decided to accept the devilishly sweet offer. This time, I will definitely get the guardian stone and become the head of the household. I will give you back as much or more than what you suffered. Until then, no one will believe. But... The image of him trying to save me, his eyes running in despair, couldn't be erased from my mind. The fiance I loved is looking at me as I am dying, but why are you running to me with those eyes, who you thought was her sister's person.

The female lead, Helna, is stabbed to death in the first chapter, and then wakes up in the past as her younger self. She has purple eyes and blue hair. She has a half-sister with reddish blonde hair, whose name is alternately spelled Viatte or Viat in different chapters. There's also a red magic stone involved in the story.